# Convert Date as given in formation string

Tags: c#, date

I have a function that converts a given date to timestamp. the date format is dynamic. for example (it could be 'dd/MM/yyyy' or 'dd-MM-yyyy' or MM/dd/yyyy).but date format is also passed as an argument in the function. i need to seperate day , month and year for this conversion. how can i separate as given in formation string

```
 public static double GetTimeStamp(string date, string format)
    {
        string[] dateToConvert = date.Split('/');

        int year=Int32.Parse(dateToConvert[2]);
        int month=Int32.Parse(dateToConvert[1]);
        int day=Int32.Parse(dateToConvert[0]);

        var baseDate = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01);
        var toDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        var numberOfSeconds = toDate.Subtract(baseDate).TotalSeconds;
        return numberOfSeconds;
    }
```

i am using '/' as a separation character. but i want to separate it as provided in the formation. if formation string is (dd-MM-yyyy). i need to seperate it using '-' charecter

Comment: Have you looked at `Datetime.ParseExact`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact

Comment: Yea It works for me. thaks

Comment: One other note: you can subtract a `DateTime` from another `DateTime`.  This will result in a `TimeSpan` object.  That type has a `Seconds` property. It would simplify your calculation

Answer (score 0):

```
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, null);


  int year = dateTime.Year;
  int month=dateTime.Month;
  int day = dateTime.Day;

  var toDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Comment: To extract the year, month, and day, you can use the relevant properties:

`int year = dateTime.Year`
`int month = dateTime.Month`
`int day = dateTime.Day`

This avoids creating strings just to read them back into ints again.

To get just the date component you can use:

`var toDate = dateTime.Date`

which returns a copy of `dateTime` with all the time information stripped (set to zero).